# How to replace occurances of a string with changing values in kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, replace

I have the current string `"number number number number number"` and I would like to replace it with `"1 2 3 4 5"`. How do i replace occurrences of a string with incrementing numbers in Kotlin?

Comment: Could you please share the code you tried so far to see where you are stuck?

Comment: Not sure why i got a down vote.... I am new to kotlin and this question has more to do with the syntax of the language than Regax. I am thinking something along the lines of mystring.replace("number" {match -> i++.toString()})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of a solution in the comment is in the right direction.

The way to do this using a single call to the standard library is this:

```
var i = 1
val result = text.replace("number".toRegex()) { _ -> "${i++}" }
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIHRleHQgPSAoMS4uNSkuam9pblRvU3RyaW5nKFwiIFwiKSB7IFwibnVtYmVyIFwifVxuICAgIHZhciBpID0gMVxuXHR2YWwgcmVzdWx0ID0gdGV4dC5yZXBsYWNlKFwibnVtYmVyXCIudG9SZWdleCgpKSB7IF8gLT4gXCIke2krK31cIiB9XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihyZXN1bHQpXG59In0=)</sup>

This [`replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) overload accepts a function that is called on each [`MatchResult`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/) (which is ignored in this case)